# list of class objects (birds). each bird has a color. how do I most efficiently get a set of all colors?

Tags: python

I have a list of class objects, say birds. Each bird has a color. I want to easily get a set of bird colors from this list of birds. What is the quickest, most efficient way to do this?

Comment: that must be a list of class instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would probably be:

```
set(bird.color for bird in birds)
```

Comment: Drop the brackets and make it a generator expression. Less syntactic clutter, takes only half the memory, and runs a few percent slower in the worst case. Also, in 2.7+ one can use a set comprehension: `{bird.color for bird in birds}`.

Comment: @delnan -- The memory is unlikely to amount to much unless `birds` is *HUGE* -- or I suppose if `birds` is a generator of some sort.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I prefer to have the `[]` to make it obvious it's a list comprehension.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, my reasons are in descending order of importance, and the latter two reasons were meant more as a "go ahead and choose the clearer one, doesn't cost you anything" than "it's more efficient, so do it". But in any case, I also think it's a good habit to not take memory (and time) one doesn't need, assuming the alternative is equally clear. Makes it easier to efficient code *when* (and if) it matters, and doesn't cost any readability or mental capacity.

Comment: @AaronDigulla But it's not a list comprehension. It's producing a set, not a list. One *can* generate an intermediate list, but there's no reason to.

Comment: @AaronDigulla there's no need of using `[]`, unless you want to store the returned list.

Comment: Isn't the result of `[xxx]` a generator anyway?

Comment: @AaronDigulla -- Nope, that's a list comprehension.  `[xxx]` list comprehension.  `(xxx)` generator expression.  The major difference is that a list comprehension builds a list right then and there.  a generator only yields objects as they are requested (via `next` or a loop).

Comment: My problem is that `a = len(bird) for bird in birds` is a syntax error. So when can I use `... for ...` without the `[]`???

Comment: @AaronDigulla `function(<generator expression>)` is shortcut for `set((<generator expression>))`, as the syntax for generator expressions is usually `(... for ... in ...)`.

Comment: @mgilson: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware that `(... for ...)` is a valid syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronDigulla -- `a = (len(bird) for bird in birds)` will work just fine (but `a` is a generator).  You can drop the parenthesis as a special case when you're putting it in a function/callable as the only argument.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: see [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in the python reference; you normally use `(...)` around a generator expression, but you can omit the extra parenthesis when invoking a callable (such as `set()`).

Comment: @mgilson It used to, but I opted to generalize to avoid the chance of another misunderstanding (that `set` is special in this regard). In any case, we both explained it differently but accurately, so it should be pretty clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
{bird.color for bird in birds}
```

[<sub>Python 2.7 or 3.x</sub>](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)